# How to auto increment an ID and add an ID to a friend class

Tags: java

I have created two classes calles friends and friendsgroup. I am trying to add friends in a array list. But i am not able to add an id in front of their details. I wanted to add an autoincrement ID incase if i add a friend in the list.
Please help me in doing that. Thank you.

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    
    public class Freunde {
        
    
        private int Id;
        
        public String LastName; 
        public String FirstName; 
        public String Email; 
        public String Address; 
            
    
        public String toString() {
            return (Id+ "," +LastName+ "," +FirstName+","+Email+Adresse);
        }
        public ArrayList<String> Kontakt = new ArrayList<String>();
        public ArrayList<String> Kontakt() 
        {
            return Kontakt;
        }
        
        Iterator<String> input = Kontakt.iterator();
    
        /**************** Starting of set methods ************************/

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.FirstName=firstName;
            }   
        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.LastName=lastName;
        }
        public void setEmail(String Email) {
            this.Email=Email;
        }
        public void setAdresse(String Adresse) {
            this.Adresse=Adresse;
        }
        
        public void setKontakt (ArrayList<String> Kontakt) {
            this.Kontakt=Kontakt;
            }
    
        /****************End of set methods************************/    
        
        /****************Starting of get methods************************/
        
        public String getFirstName() {
            return FirstName;
        }
        
        public String getLastName() {
            return LastName;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return Email;
        }
        
        public String getAdresse() {
            return Adresse;
        }
        public ArrayList<String> getKontakt() {
            return Kontakt;
        }
        /****************End of get methods************************/
        
        public int getId() {
            return Id++;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            Id = id;
        }
        /****************add a friend method************************/
        public void addfriend() {   
    
        Kontakt.add(FirstName);
        Kontakt.add(LastName);
        Kontakt.add(Email);
        Kontakt.add(Adresse);
        }   
        /****************remove a friend method************************/
        public void remove(){
        Kontakt.remove(FirstName);
        Kontakt.remove(LastName);
        Kontakt.remove(Email);
        Kontakt.remove(Adresse);
        }
        /****************change a friend method************************/    
        public void change()
        {
        Kontakt.set(0, FirstName);
        Kontakt.set(1, LastName);
        Kontakt.set(5, Email);
        Kontakt.set(6, Adresse);
        }   
        /****************End of array methods************************/
    
        /**************** Durchsuche alles nach Name *********************/
    
        public void search(String Name) {
            for (int i = 0; i < Kontakt.size(); i++) {
                if (Kontakt.get(i).equals(Name)) {
                    System.out.println("element found:"+ Kontakt.get(i).equals(Name));
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        
        
        public boolean contains(String bornlist) {
            return false;
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
    
        public static int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    
        public int get(int i) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    
        public void contains() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        
         public void setKontakt(int id, String firstname, String lastname, String email, String adresse)
            {
                
                setFirstName(firstname);
                setLastName(lastname);
                setEmail(email);
                setAdresse(adresse);
            }//end constructor for friend
    
    
        public void setKontakt(String vorname2, String name2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    
    
        public static Iterator<String> iterator() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }
    
       
        }
```

In my other class inoder to add a friend i have something like

```
if (selection == 2) { // Add friend
                System.out.println("Kontaktdata");
                System.out.println("---------------------");
                System.out.printf("Firstname: ");
                input = new Scanner(System.in);
                String vorname = input.next();
                System.out.printf("LastName: ");
                String name = input.next();
                System.out.printf("Email: ");
                String email = input.next();
                System.out.printf("Adresse: ");
                String adresse = input.next();

                bornList.setKontakt(id, firstname, lastname, email, adresse);    
                bornList.add(); // adds the friend to the array list
                System.out.println("back to menu");
                System.in.read();
                Start.menü();
                selection = input.nextInt();

            }
```

i am trying to add friend though

```
public void addfriend() { 
Kontakt.get(id); 
Kontakt.add(FirstName); 
Kontakt.add(LastName);
Kontakt.add(Email); 
Kontakt.add(Adresse); 
}
```

which i call in another function

```
bornList.setKontakt(id, firstname, lastname, email, adresse); bornList.addfriend(); //
```

adds the friend to the array list. But i get a thread error.

But i get output something like id 0.
Kontakt:0,Müller,Thomas,Telefon:016396404304,10/01/1992,01879845649thomas.mueller@xyz.de,abcdef7, 12303 Berg, Australia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditch the id-parameter and replace it with a private static field (called e.g. nextId):

```
private static int nextId = 0;
```

As it is a static field, it is not dependent on a single object but rather on the entire class. In order for this to now work, execute the following code inside of the constructor:

```
this.id = nextId;
nextId++;
```

This increases the static field "nextId" by one each time a new Object is created and assigns unique IDs to every Object. If you intent to create more Objects than the maximum value of the Integer class (2147483647) this will cause an exception. In this case, use a long or a BigInteger instead.

P.S.: Attributes, such as "Id" should **always** start with a lowercase letter!
P.P.S.: hoffentlich trifft Thomas Müller heute! :^)

Comment: i am trying to add friend though public void addfriend() {   
 Kontakt.get(id);
    Kontakt.add(FirstName);
        Kontakt.add(LastName);
        Kontakt.add(Email);
        Kontakt.add(Adresse); } which i call in another function             
 bornList.setKontakt(id, firstname, lastname, email, adresse);                   
 bornList.addfriend(); // adds the friend to the array list But i get a thread error.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achieve something similar to what you want is to have a `static` integer variable that will be used as an id generator. Each time you create a new instance of a `Friend` object you could then simply fetch the current value and increment it by one. A simple example would like something like this:

```java
public class Friend {

    private static int idCache = 0;

    private final int id;

    private String lastName;
    public String getLastName() { return lastName; }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) { this.lastName = lastName; }

    private String firstName;
    public String getFirstName() { return firstName; }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) { this.firstName = firstName; }

    private String email;
    public String getEmail() { return email; }
    public void setEmail(String email) { this.email = email; }

    private String address;
    public String getAddress() { return address; }
    public void setAddress(String address) { this.address = address; }

    public Friend() {
        this.id = idCache++;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "Friend{" +
        "id=" + id +
        ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
        ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
        ", email='" + email + '\'' +
        ", address='" + address + '\'' +
        '}';
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Friend friend = new Friend();
            System.out.println(friend);
    }
    }

}
```

I hope this makes sense to you and is helpful.

Comment: hallo @akortex91. i am trying to add friend though public void addfriend() { Kontakt.get(id); Kontakt.add(FirstName); Kontakt.add(LastName); Kontakt.add(Email); Kontakt.add(Adresse); } which i call in another function bornList.setKontakt(id, firstname, lastname, email, adresse); bornList.addfriend(); // adds the friend to the array list But i get a thread error.